# Frame Rate of a webcam reduces when connected to an android device

Tags: android, android-camera, frame-rate

When I connect my webcam to a laptop it gives a framerate of 30fps.
However when I connect the same webcam to an android device the frame rate is less than 15 fps.

I have used Camera.getPreviewFpsRange() to check the maximum possible fps i can obtain on the android device.

Why does this happen and is there any way of increasing the frame rate?

Comment: The Camera method applies to the internal cameras.  How are you connecting your webcam to the Android device?  What camera, device, and version of Android?

Comment: Webcam through a USB to an android mini pc.Android version 4.1.1